# Why LED on desktop tower blinks when I press num-lock key?

Tags: desktop-computer, numlock

Whenever I press NumLock key, a small LED on desktop tower blinks once. Can someone explain it why this happens ?
The led has symbol which looks like a battery or disk.

Edit: LED does not blink when I press capslock or scroll lock.
This happens in Ubuntu only. While using Windows led doesn't blink.

Comment: CPUs don’t have LEDs. What are you referring to? Perhaps the PC case?

Comment: @Daniel B I will share a video for more clarity.

Comment: Does it blink _immediately_ or does it blink e.g. exactly a second later or so?

Comment: By "CPU" he means the desktop tower itself. For some reason, lots of people call a desktop PC a "CPU". The LED is the hard drive activity LED. When he enables/disables Num Lock, the computer briefly accesses the hard drive.

Comment: @wrecclesham thanks for pointing out. I have edited the question. Since the school time teachers have been teaching us "it is called CPU".

Comment: @grawity Blinks immediately\

Comment: [This is a CPU](https://get.pxhere.com/photo/mobile-technology-processor-cpu-editorial-intel-microcontroller-electronic-device-personal-computer-hardware-electronics-accessory-network-interface-controller-core-i7-1248612.jpg).

Answer (score 2):

Most likely option: Windows records your NumLock preference in the [Registry](https://www.google.com/search?q=InitialKeyboardIndicators), and then flushes the Registry change to the disk (updating the NTUSER.DAT file).

However, you can use [ProcMon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to check what actual activity is happening. (Note that it might generate disk activity on its own, and you might need to exclude a lot of processes before you can see anything useful.)

Comment: That's interesting. I always thought it would only need to exist in RAM because the Num Lock state doesn't persist between reboots.

Comment: Maybe I'm confusing this with another OS which did store it persistently?

Comment: I know in the BIOS you can usually specify the Num Lock status at boot but I'm not sure if it's effectively Yes/No or Yes/last state remembered by Windows. I'll experiment and see how it works on my PC.

Comment: On my parent's Windows 10 laptops the state of NumLock is surely persisted between reboots (and after a full power down). I doubt it's the laptop/external keyboard itself that is doing that, but maybe it is.

Comment: But it is not same case with caps and scroll lock

Comment: Because Caps Lock and Scroll Lock are not persisted (it doesn't make much sense to persist them from usability point of view).